# Error [fatal] ERR_SUBPROCESS_NON_ZERO_EXIT while 'npx cap run android --list'

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

When I try to `npx cap run android` command I'm getting `[fatal] ERR_SUBPROCESS_NON_ZERO_EXIT`.

`npx cap open android` work what I expected and I can lunch the application via android studio on my real device.

These are my capacitor version;

```
 npx cap doctor android

   Capacitor Doctor   

Latest Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: unknown
  @capacitor/core: unknown
  @capacitor/android: unknown
  @capacitor/ios: unknown

Installed Dependencies:

  @capacitor/ios: not installed
  @capacitor/cli: 3.0.0
  @capacitor/core: 3.0.0
  @capacitor/android: 3.0.0

[success] Android looking great!
```

```
npx cap run   
            
✔ Please choose a platform to run: › android
✔ Copying web assets from build to apps/mobile/android/app/src/main/assets/public in 39.06ms
✔ Creating capacitor.config.json in apps/mobile/android/app/src/main/assets in 1.44ms
⠙ copy android [info] Found 1 Cordova plugin for android:
       cordova-plugin-ionic@5.4.7
✔ copy android in 93.34ms
✔ Updating Android plugins in 10.88ms
[info] Found 1 Cordova plugin for android:
       cordova-plugin-ionic@5.4.7
⠙ update android [warn] Plugins are missing dependencies.
       Cordova plugin dependencies must be installed in your project (e.g. w/ npm install).
       
       cordova-plugin-ionic is missing dependencies:
       - cordova-plugin-whitelist (^1.3.3)
       
✔ update android in 76.39ms
[error] ERR_SUBPROCESS_NON_ZERO_EXIT
```

**Actually, I want to run livereload mode but I'm getting a similar error:**

```
ionic capacitor run android --livereload --external

[ERROR] Error while getting Capacitor CLI version.
        
        ERR_SUBPROCESS_NON_ZERO_EXIT
```

Does anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please tell how you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the ionic framework to build a project. I think they already combine capacitors to their project, so you're not necessarily using "npx capacitor ...." anymore. Try Below typing in cmd to see how it work.

> `ionic repair`
> this one will help you remove node_modules and package-lock then reinstalled that, make sure package.json no problem.
> After reinstall completed. Then:

> `ionic build`

after having a dist folder. Then next step type:

> `ionic cap add android`
> `ionic cap open android`

then make apk and try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have remark in the reply of the order.
It is indicated ... latest dependence

```
npx cap doctor android
```

Capacitor Doctor

```
 Latest Dependencies:

 @capacitor/cli: unknown
 @capacitor/core: unknown
 @capacitor/android: unknown
 @capacitor/ios: unknown
```

So the solution is simply to add @latest when adding the different dependencies.

For example for the Android platform:
`yarn add @capacitor/android@latest`